# HowTo set response status code in CXF SOAP OneWay request on error

Tags: http, cxf, jax-ws

I have implemented a @OneWay JAX-RS service with Apache CXF ( a dropwizard application ). When called with invalid structure, causing an unmarshalling error in DocLiteralInInterceptor, http status code 200 is returned to client. To make the calling process  recognize the fault, I need to return status 400 or 500, along with the error text from  Unmarshalling Error.

I recognized that, after the error, the "in" interceptor chain is unwound ( interceptors handleFault-methods are called in reverse order ), so I installed an interceptor at the start of the "in"-chain ( last on unwinding ) with

```
public CustomSOAPInterceptor(String chainname) {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    getBefore().add(PolicyInInterceptor.class.getName());
    this.chainname=chainname;
}
```

Within my handleFault-Method I can seperate the fault message and recognize the unmarshall error. But I am not succeeding in setting the response.

I tried

```
Fault f = (Fault) e;
f.setStatusCode(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
```

and

```
Response response = Response
    .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
    .entity(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode() + " " + f.getLocalizedMessage())
    .build();
soapMessage.getExchange().put(Response.class, response);
```

and

```
message.put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
```

Where is the response set and how can I overwrite it ?

Tx for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I know, its kind of late, but for those who are looking for a solution:

In my application, the following works:

```
public void handleFault(SoapMessage soapMessage) {
    /* some code to test for specific error deleted */
    Exchange exchange = soapMessage.getExchange();
    Message outMessage = exchange.getOutMessage();
    if (outMessage == null) {
        Endpoint endpoint = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);
        outMessage = endpoint.getBinding().createMessage();
        exchange.setOutMessage(outMessage);
    }
    try {
        EndpointReferenceType target = exchange.get(EndpointReferenceType.class);
        Conduit conduit = exchange.getDestination().getBackChannel(soapMessage);
        exchange.setConduit(conduit);
        conduit.prepare(outMessage);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    Object resp = outMessage.get("HTTP.RESPONSE");

    if (resp != null && resp instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        response.setStatus(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
    }
    soapMessage.getInterceptorChain().abort();
}
```